# Make column stretch to fill whatever space it can in Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this issue:

[image]

The html is as follows:

```
<div class="row">
    <div ng-cloak class="col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <form class="form">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 no-wrap">
        <span class="push-buttons-away-from-search-bar btn-group" role="group">
            <a class="btn btn-lg" href="">A link</a>
            <a class="btn btn-lg" href="">Another link</a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can you think of a responsive (bootstrap) way of making the search bartake up all space it can, and leave space for the 2 buttons on the side.

Notice the spacing between the 2 buttons, the button grouping styling was getting in the way... Perhaps you suggest using button groups?

Comment: How about using `margin-right` on the links `DIV`?

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to do this using bootstrap grid system. Bootstrap will always calculate appropriate column width, but in yuor case you need fixed column width for buttons. I would suggest to do this without bootstrap - place everything in one column that has 12-cols width like here http://jsfiddle.net/1j0kt3j4/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're likely looking for, assuming you're using Bootstrap 3, is Justified Buttons. Red: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups-justified

Example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="Justified button group">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Left</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Right</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5gpmwmkk/): Note that this can be extended to more than one button.

---

**Update**

Since you need the input to scale without the buttons scaling, have you tried Segmented Buttons on an Input Group? Ref: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons-segmented

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button One</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button Two</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button Three</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0hL6tL23/): Note this won't give you a space between the buttons.

Comment: Very nice, almost... I think it'll have to be the other way around... Otherwise the buttons have a lot of padding left and right. Obviously i don't mind an input field getting longer, but not the buttons. Cool to know though! Good try!

Comment: No problem Sephiroth :)

Comment: Tell me what you cherish most. Give me the pleasure of taking it away. Hehehe.

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 Have you considered using segmented buttons on input groups?

Comment: Right, i'm going to try and style this segment stuff to how i'd like it to look. I think  you're spot on here... The input grouping is similar, but was having troubles styling it nicely. Lemme give this a try